# PHP - Split string on specific characters

Tags: php, string, split

I'm working on a project where I downloaded thousands laws from the governments website (legality all in order). I am trying to split the name of the files so I can sort them better in my website. The file is designed as such

`48600003801.html`

I am running a foreach loop on the `scandir()` function. I have around 20,000+ files as such. I want to do the following:

```
Chapter: 486
Section: 380

      CH.   ART.  SEC.
Split 486 | 000 | 0380 | 1

// PHP code
$files = scandir('stathtml/');
    foreach ($files as $file) {

        // Change this to a split function and then echo certain parts
        // of it out to test.
        echo $file . "<br>";

    }
```

How would I go about splitting such a string type up seeing that they are almost all different lengths?

Comment: substr or preg_split

Comment: Please add a little bit more of examples. Is always the first 3 digits the chapter and the 4 before the last the section???

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for. I spent twenty minutes googlin it and couldn't figure out the function name. I kept getting `spilt()` and `explode()` which wasn't what I needed.

Comment: @bugs2919 The first three are the chapter, the second 3 were the article, the next four is the section, and the last is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
// PHP code
    $files = scandir('stathtml/');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $arr1 = substr($files, -5);
            $arr1 = substr($arr1, 4);
            $arr2 = substr($files, 3);
            echo $file . "<br>";
            echo "section ".$arr1 . "<br>";
            echo "chapter".$arr2 . "<br>";
        }
```

Comment: Not precisely what I used, but very close. Thanks